Does the contraction $f_{ijk} f_{i mn}$ simplify to $\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn} +\ldots$ for structure constants $f_{ijk}$?
Consider the 3D Levi-Cevita symbol $\varepsilon_{ijk}$. Using Einstein summation convention, one has the identity
$$
\varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{imn} = \delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn} \delta_{km}
$$
where $\delta_{jm}$ is the Kronecker delta.
My question is whether the structure constants of a Lie Algebra satisfy some kind of analogous relation (likely more complicated, if at all). The structure constants $f_{ijk}$ satisfy
$$
[T_{i}, T_{j}] = f_{ijk} T_{k}
$$
where $T_i$ are generators of the Lie Algebra.
I know that there is a Jacobi identity,
$$
f_{ade} f_{bcd} + f_{bde} f_{cad} + f_{cde} f_{abd} = 0 \ ,
$$
which might be related, but is there some simple way of expressing $f_{ijk} f_{i mn}$ analogous to the Levi-Cevita symbol?
